# ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary Implicit declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I use this line of code

`NSString *address = ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(placemark.addressDictionary, NO);`

I got this error

`Implicit declaration of function 'ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary' is invalid in C99`

The strange part is that for iOS7 it does not trigger the error while for iOS8 it does.

Has anyone met the same problem?

Comment: import AddressBookUI framework

Comment: I actually have used this line of code before without any problem, even for iOS8. And for another file I also used this line, it works fine. In a UIViewController file with an extra UITextView, this problem occurs. I guess it is maybe due to the textView. @matt

Comment: also shows `Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC` as error msg and `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSString *__strong' from 'int'` as warning msg

Comment: Just fyi, ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary is deprecated in iOS 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce that issue is by forgetting to import the AddressBookUI framework. In other words, if I say this, it compiles:

```
@import AddressBookUI;
@import CoreLocation;
@implementation Thing
- (void) test {
    CLPlacemark* p = [CLPlacemark new];
    NSString *address = ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(p.addressDictionary, NO);
}
@end
```

But if I comment out the first `@import` line, I get your error. Is that the mistake you're making?

Comment: you saved me... I mistakenly imported `#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>`